# Multi level props in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've recently started learning react. I can't understand this:

> `this.props.message.text`

I know that `message` is an object with a key value pair in it, the key being `text`.
But my problem is when we want to pass the prop to the component:

> `<Component message={message}>`

My question is why should we write `message={message}`?

Why shouldn't we write `message={message.text}` instead so that we know we want `text`?

How does it know we want `text` in the `message` object?

Comment: The component expects the message, not just the message text. Why? Don't know-out of context impossible to guess other than in general you give components what they expect.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what the `Component` is doing. Let's say you have more properties in your message object, e.g :

```
{
  text: 'this is my message',
  author: 'odiwxe',
  sentAt: '2018-05-30T12:30:00'
}
```

Then your `Component` might want all that information in order to display it so you could pass it as you have done like:

```
<Component message={message}>
```

Otherwise, if your `Component` only cares about the message text you could potentially change it to something like this:

```
<Component messageText={message.text}>
```

It's up to you!

Comment: Thanks. For context, this is the link:
https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/react/components

My prpblem is in the `renderTasks` function in App.js file. It has used `task._id` for the id but for the task text it has only written `task`.

Comment: Yes, you are correct - there is actually no need to pass the whole task in the case of the tutorial as it only uses the `text` property. However, passing the whole `task` object allows you to easily change the `Task` component if more properties are added to the object without having to change the parent to pass down new props

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it does not.
When we want the text of the message we have to access the data using the props passed to the child component in this way:

```
{this.props.message.text}
```

So, when any child component requires data which is sent by it's parent you need to tell the object name in which you require the data in child.
for Example:

```
<Parent Component {

//Some code//


<ChildComponent propsName = {propsData}
}
```

Then this data will be accessible in child component in this form:

```
<ChildComponent

{this.props.propsName}

}
```

So, this is the way of passing the data from parent to child and for achieving this you need to use props.

> //Update

It has used task for the task but task.*id for the key because they just want the key in that case and task object is used in the  component for some other functioning like printing the text written in that which cannot be fetched from task*.id individually.

According to me, the task object is somewhat like this:

```
task{
"text": "value"
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Please read my comment on Christos Dimitroulas's answer to this question. Can you check that and help me?

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for.